# Как отобразить в запросе SQL значения только у последней строки?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Есть две таблицы, первая Phones:

| Ph_ID | Phone_Num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |

и вторая Sales:

| Sale_ID | Ph_ID | Model_ID | DateOfSale | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1/07/2020 | 45000 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 3/07/2020 | 57000 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 23/07/2020 | 44000 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 | 2/08/2020 | 85000 |

необходимо вывести номера телефонов(Phone_Num), проданных с 01.07.2020 по 30.07.2020 и стоимость последней (в этом диапазоне) продажи.

Я сделал код для вывода всех Phone_Num в этом периоде, но как вывести стоимость последней продажи?

```
select p.phone_num, up.dateofsales
from sales up 
join phones p  
on up.ph_id = p.ph_id 
where up.dt >= to_date('01.07.2020' ,'DD/MM/YY') and up.dt <= to_date('30.07.2020' ,'DD/MM/YY') order by 2
```

Comment: Куда вывести? Добавить отдельным полем к каждой записи?

Comment: номеров телефонов может быть несколько (или ни одного). Стоимость последней (последней з по дате ведь?) продажи - одна. Это наводит на мысль, что делать это нужно разными запросами

Comment: *необходимо вывести номера телефонов(Phone_Num), проданных с 01.07.2020 по 30.07.2020 и стоимость последней (в этом диапазоне) продажи.* Это данные разных уровней группировки, поэтому правильное решение - использовать отдельные запросы.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1527f4b26971cabab58d7f6b6888ec3e)):

```
select p.phone_num, s.dateofsale, price,
    first_value (price) over (partition by p.phone_num order by s.dateofsale desc) lastprice
from sales s 
join phones p on p.ph_id = s.ph_id 
where s.dateofsale between date'2020-07-01' and date'2020-07-30' 
order by 2
/

 PHONE_NUM DATEOFSALE               PRICE  LASTPRICE
---------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
      2000 2020-07-01 00:00:00      45000      44000
      2000 2020-07-23 00:00:00      44000      44000
```